# Desktop.browse(new URI("http://")) - Как определить, когда браузер открылся. Нужен "листенер"

Tags: java

Есть небольшая проблемка по поводу вызова браузера и временных файлов.

Данным образом с интернета скачивается HTML-документ и сохраняется в папку временных файлов:

```
HttpURLConnection i2 = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("...").openConnection();
...
BufferedReader i3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i2.getInputStream()));
String i4 = "";
while (true) {
    String i5 = i3.readLine();
    if (i5 == null) {
        i3.close();
        break;
    } else {
        i4 += i5 + System.lineSeparator();
    }
}
i2.disconnect();
File i5 = File.createTempFile("myTempFile", ".html");
FileOutputStream i6 = new FileOutputStream(i5);
i6.write(i4.split("...")[0].getBytes("UTF-8"));
i6.flush();
i6.close();
```

Вот метод, вызывающий браузер, назначенный в системе по умолчанию:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("file:///" + i5.getAbsolutePath().replace(File.separator, "/")));
```

Различные HTML-документы скачиваются с интернета настолько часто, что за несколько дней их более тысячи. Ведь нужно же удалить эти файлы после использования. Я задался вопросом "а как же это сделать..", как определить когда открылся браузер? То есть, к примеру, Google Chrome у меня запускаться может до 5 секунд, а затем уже грузит нужный HTML-документ, размер которого не ограничен. Следовательно, он и несколько минут может загружаться. Как сделать "листенер", который будет мне сообщать, когда загрузился браузер с моим `URI`.

Comment: Не понятен полностью ваш юзкейс. Почему нельзя чистить файлы по расписанию?

Comment: Как расписание задать то если я не знаю когда браузер файл полностью прочитал? В этом то и проблема.

Comment: Просто чистить папку раз в сутки.

Comment: Компьютер работает без передышки круглосуточно. Я не знаю, когда браузер файлы скачивает, так сервер устроен.

Comment: Еще раз: будет проще вам что-то посоветовать, если вы опишите общую задачу. Процесс идет по расписанию или непрерывно? Компьютер, на котором все это происходит условно "ваш" или "вражеский"? Пользователь смотрит в браузер или вы там какие-то скрипты гоняете? Браузер всегда конкретный или может быть любой: Пока я вижу два варианта: чистить всю папку в какой-то момент (ночь, старт приложения, что угодно в зависимости от профиля использования вашего ПО) либо написать свой плагин в браузер, который будет уведомлять ваш сервер о чем захотите.

Comment: Боже мой. Где-то, выражусь "в горах" запущен сервер. На него **не знаю когда** заходит браузер и скачивает определённые нужные ему файлы и открывает их. В них Javascript выполняется. Вот и нужно, чтобы после того, как файл браузером прочитался, он должен удалиться и **навсегда исчезнуть** с папки временных файлов. Если определять нельзя, когда этот Desktop открыл браузер, так и скажите, что *мол нужно другой способ искать*. Других способов не вижу, нужно именно так. Если нельзя это сделать, то я просто закрою вопрос.

Comment: Что умеет делать `Desktop.browse()` описано в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)). Ни о каких Listener-ах там речи нет. Я вам предлагаю варианты решения вашей исходной задачи, потому что тут классическая проблема XY.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709

Comment: а зачем скачивать файл? почему не сразу открыть нужный url в браузере?

Comment: При данном подходе Ваша задача нерешаема, поскольку `Desktop.browse()` не содержит нужных Вам средств. Ищите другой путь и решения. Возможно, если Вы расскажите большой о своих целях, кто-то подберет Вам более подходящее к Вашей задаче решение.

Comment: @Grundy, потому что не с HTTP сервера файл скачивается и протокол другой.

Comment: @L'Esperanza возможно в Java есть способ отследить не открытие страницы, а просто закрытие браузера, если Вас устроит такой вариант(вроде запуска процесса и ожидания его окончания).

Comment: @AlexKrass, возможно. Расскажите как?